# how to pass session value in javascript and if session true my html button should be invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want that my session value check in **javascript** and if the value is 1 the html button should be invisible in page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try _anything_ so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP.Net MVC in your controller set the variable that contain button's visibility information (it may be model's var or ViewBag/ViewData var):

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.isInvisible = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

then in the view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var myBool = '@ViewBag.isInvisible';
        var isInvisible = (myBool == 'True');
        if (isInvisible) {
            $('#button').hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<button id="button">@ViewBag.isInvisible</button>
```

this example requires jquery

Comment: No i am not using MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideButton() {
            if ('<%=Session["MySession"] %>' == '1') {
                $('#' + '<%=MyButton.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
                $('#MyButton1').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="HideButton();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <input type="submit" title="Save" id="MyButton1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and .cs

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MySession"] = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using html button. so how i write a javascript for html button

Comment: now see this i hope you find what is needed i guess

Comment: ok what i have to write for when session=0 the button should be visible

Comment: i think you can write an else condition you want spoon feeding